# How do you calculate the height of balanced Binary Search Tree in O(log n) times complexity?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, big-o, binary-search-tree

I understand that in order to compute the height of a Binary Search Tree in O(n) we can use the following function

```
public static int treeHeight(Node root) {
      if (root == null) {
         return -1;
      }

      int left = treeHeight(root.left) + 1;
      int right = treeHeight(root.right) + 1;

      return Math.max(left, right);
   }
```

However, given the fact that the tree is [balanced][2] how can we calculate the height of Binary Search Tree in O(log n).

The given problem:

Comment: You need to define "balanced". Red-black trees are normally considered to be self-balancing (hence always "balanced"), but you can't determine the height of an arbitrary red-black tree without potentially examining the whole tree.

Comment: Ok sorry for the confusion I have edited my original post to refer to the definition of balanced that I am referring to.

Comment: Can the nodes in the bottom row be in arbitrary branches of the tree? If the bottom row were filled out left-to-right you could descend down the left side to compute the height. But if those extra "+1" nodes could be anywhere then I'm not sure you can compute the height in O(log n). You could have to examine up to n/2 nodes at the bottom of the tree to see if there are any stragglers.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I will refer to the exact question that I was given. However, that is was I was thinking that is why I felt the need to post this question.

Comment: The height of a tree balanced in such a way should be `ceil(log(n+1))`, which can be computed in `O(log n)` time via repeated division.

Comment: I have rolled back to the previous version so that the image, which adds vital context, will show. That's more important to the question than your insistence on changing the name of your function. You do not have permissions to post pictures. The person who edited your question to make the image visible was doing you a favor. Accept it with good grace.

Answer (score 1):

**It's not possible.**

If the bottom row were filled out in a predictable fashion it could be done. For example, if the last row were always filled out left-to-right you could descend down the left side in O(log n) time since the left side would be guaranteed to have max height.

In the problem statement the nodes in the bottom row can be anywhere. The exact height can't be computed in O(log n) time. You can get within 1 of the height in O(log n) steps, but to get the exact height you may have to examine up to n/2 nodes at the bottom of the tree to find the stragglers (if any).

The worst case is if the last level is completely full and every single node in the last level has to be checked for children. There would be n/2 nodes and two checks per node, thus n checks in total. There wouldn't be any children in this case, but it'd still take O(n) checks to verify it.